# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined [discord.js]

Tags: discord, discord.js

Im getting this error for writing this "unban" codes to unban.js

Re-installed discord.js library, re-writed the code but did'nt worked.

```
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  if (!message.member.roles.find(role => role.name === "| Ban Hammer")) {
    return message.channel.send(
      "**Kanka `| Ban Hammer` yetkisine sahip değilsin.**"
    );
  }

  let bannedMember = await client.fetchUser(args[0]);
  if (!bannedMember) {
    return message.channel.send(`**Bir id yazmalısın.**`);
  }

  let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
  if (!reason) {
    reason = "Bir sebep belirtilmedi.";
  }

  try {
    message.guild.unban(bannedMember, { reason: reason });
    message.react(emoji);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
};

module.exports.conf = {
  name: "unban"
};
```

[ Sorry guys, my english is bad. ]

Comment: Can you show the error message

Comment: Your code is not failing in any of the code you have provided, the error message says that is cannot get `id`, yet you are not trying to get the `id` of anything throughout the entire code block. Please update with more information so that people can help you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code does not reference `id` *in that particular file*.
When looking for debugging help, please attach the full, or at least *main* error message, like [Cursed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10675707/cursed) said. my only suggestion would be that `id` might be misused in a different file, or incorrectly referenced elsewhere.